# How to fix selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find when the seller became a seller on `bol.com` by doing

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/looliving-nl/1146429/")
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/p").text
print(date)
```

I expected it to print `Actief sinds: 29 januari 2016`, but instead it returns  an error about my `find_element_by_xpath()` query:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/p"}
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the date `Actief sinds: 29 januari 2016`  You need to Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_element_located` and following xpath.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/looliving-nl/1146429/")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h1[@data-test='seller_name']/following::p[@data-test='seller_active']"))).text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/looliving-nl/1146429/")
date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/p")).text
```

OR simply put implicit wait

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bol.com/nl/v/looliving-nl/1146429/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/p").text
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a WebDriverWait to wait for the elment to be present:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPath, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/p"))
    )
```

Comment: When I do this I get the error ```NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined``` and when I also do ```from selenium import WebDriverWait``` it says ```ImportError: cannot import name 'WebDriverWait' from 'selenium' (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py)```. Are you sure that sode is python?

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait